# list of github repository files along with latest commiter

Tags: git, github, github-api

I want to have all files content with their latest committer. Repository size is relatively small, less than 100 files.

I see one way to do that which seems bad performance-wise. Get [repository tree](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/) and then check to each every sha belongs to ( skipping already knowns sha's ). [Tarball](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/downloads/) the repository and download. This will cause inconsistency since downloading tarball and tree/sha' owner might run into race condition.

Any better solution in any programming language is fine ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`git blame`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame) to show what revision and author last modified each line of a file. Combined with `find`, you can check all the files content with their committer.

This bash script finds out all the files in current directory recursively, and `git blame` all the files and write the output to `/tmp/git_files.log`

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo {}; git blame {}; echo;' \; > /tmp/git_files.log
```

Comment: do you know the way to achieve the same via github API ?

Comment: seems no blame API available for v3. you should check GraphQL API v4 https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/object/blame/